# when I click on Register here, it does not go to the next activity

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

when I click on Logout button it goes to the next activity but, On the next activity when  I click on the "Register here" to go to the next activity it says unfortunately , Login has stopped. Please help me out.

## Main Activity

```
package com.example.namrata.login;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements     View.OnClickListener {

Button blogout;
EditText uname1, name1, age1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    uname1 =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname1);
    name1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name1);
    age1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age1);

    blogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blogout);

    blogout.setOnClickListener(this);


}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.blogout:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
            break;
    }

}


}
```

## Login Activity

```
package com.example.namrata.login;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

   Button blogin;
   EditText uname, pass;
   TextView registerLink;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    uname =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);
    registerLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.registerLink);

    blogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blogin);

    blogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    registerLink.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.registerLink:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Register.class));


        break;

        case R.id.blogin:
            break;


       }
   }

}
```

## Register Acitvity

```
package com.example.namrata.login;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

 Button bregister;
 EditText uname2, pass1, name2, age2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    uname2 =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname2);
    pass1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass1);
    name2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name2);
    age2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age2);

    bregister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blogin);

    bregister.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.bregister:



            break;
        }

     }

  }
```

## activity_login layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
android:background="#28e317"
android:backgroundTint="#ffffff">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Username"
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/uname"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Password"
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/pass"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login"
    android:id="@+id/blogin"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#7c82f9"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Register Here."
    android:id="@+id/registerLink"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />
```

## activity_main layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    >


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/name2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Age"
    android:id="@+id/age"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/age2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Username"
    android:id="@+id/username1"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/uname2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Logout"
    android:id="@+id/blogout"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#7c82f9"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
```

## activity_register layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#28e317"
    android:backgroundTint="#ffffff">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/name1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Age"
    android:id="@+id/age"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/age1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Username"
    android:id="@+id/username1"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/uname1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Password"
    android:id="@+id/password1"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/pass1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Register"
    android:id="@+id/bregister"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#7c82f9"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
```

## Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.namrata.login">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Register"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Show stack-trace from logcat

Comment: you want to logout on button click..

Comment: Make this changes in your Register Class---> Replace this---> bregister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blogin); with this--->bregister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bregister); your problem will be solved

Comment: Ur MainActivity is not linking with activity_main ...

Comment: Thanks a lot .. such an Idiot I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In register activity xml you have `android:id="@+id/bregister"`

but in `RegisterActivity` you searching for login button

`bregister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blogin);`

which is null that is why you are getting **null pointer exception** i think change it to

`bregister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bregister);`

Comment: Thanks a lot .. such an Idiot I am

Answer (score 0):

In your layout file for register activity (`activity_register`) you have:

```
android:id="@+id/bregister"
```

but in `Register` Activity.java you're doing:

```
bregister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blogin);
```

so `register` is set to `null`. Hence it crashes on:

```
bregister.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Mark one answer as correct, if you've solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Your onClick method in MainActivity is not the overrided one that's why it's not getting called automatically.Create it as you have create onClick method in LoginActivity

Answer (score 0):

In your First Activity class `MainActivity` you are using this layout class

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

You should use

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
```

and in this `activity_login` layout you should 
change TextView is Register here To Button

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Register Here."
    android:id="@+id/registerLink"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />
```

Remove this and use button instead of `TextView`.